Honda Civic 2018 1L turbo makes a noise when accelerating
My Honda Civic 2018 1L turbo makes a noise when I am accelerating. It is a bit hard to describe what the noise is like, but it sounds like air escaping a small gap and has some metallic tone to it.
The noise doesn't come when I depress the gas pedal slightly. It only comes after I depress it beyond a certain level.
The noise is continuous, and becomes louder the more I depress the pedal.
It fades away in about half a second after I take the foot away from the gas pedal.
The noise doesn't come when rev up in parking gear.
I took the car to a mechanic, and he replaced the turbocharger with a spare unit he had in the garage, but the noise was still there.
He disconnected the hose coming out the turbo, before the intake manifold, and the noise was not there.
Recently an oil leak repair was done on the car, where the oil was leaking between the engine and the gearbox. An O ring like seal was replaced to fix it, and the gearbox was taken out to replace it. I don't remember this noise before the repair was done, and only noticed the noise after the repair. Not sure whether there is a connection between the noise and the repair done.
What could be the reason for the noise?

I had this once on my turbo vehicle. I only heard the noise when accelerating hard uphill with my window open while passing a property that had a solid fence near the road. The sound reflected off the fence and back to the car.
In my case, a spring clamp on a rubber air duct had broken, and the turbo air pressure in the duct under high boost was enough to force the duct off its flange and form an air gap where high pressure air would escape and make the noise. When pressure dropped, the soft rubber duct would spring back and close the gap, so no air would escape.
You need to trace the air induction system, all its ducts and all its connectors and clamps from the output of the turbo to the intake manifold. Physically move every piece and check it for a solid connection. You may find that a clamp is missing, loose or broken.
It's possible that the mechanic who fixed the oil leak had to disconnect some portion of the air induction system and failed to replace it properly. It may also be connected tight, but off-axis allowing air to escape.

Turned out it was something to do with the connection of hoses. Mechanic didn't tell me exactly what hose though.
